# SQL insert within MySQL hosted on a raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I have created a database called fruits within it I have created a table called fruits_info.

With headings of fruits_name VARCHAR(25), fruits_description VARCHAR(75), fruits_price FLOAT.

When I try and insert values to the table I use this function.

```
INSERT INTO fruits.fruits_info VALUES(`Peaches`, `Fresh peaches from Bengal`, `1.90`);
```

I then get this error message.

> Error 1054 (42s22):Unknown column `peaches` in `field list`

Comment: Using backticks denotes a column. Using quotes denotes a string. Also potentially a bad idea to use FLOAT for prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `` ` `` use `'`.

```
INSERT INTO fruits.fruits_info VALUES('Peaches', 'Fresh peaches from Bengal', '1.90');
```

The backtick (`` ` ``) is for specifying a column.
The single quote (`'`) is for a value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO fruits.fruits_info VALUES('Peaches', 'Fresh peaches from 
Bengal', '1.90');
```